# How to subset specific object properly in JS

Tags: javascript, api, object

I'm currently doing some practice and i want to print the titles of each movie on this api:

> https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies?Year=1998

Basically, I want each title to be printed for the first page (or preferably a specific page).

This is the code I have:

```
<script>
function printTItles(year) {
  var res;
  
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      
      for(var i=0;i<res.per_page;i++){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.data.i.Title;
      }
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies?Year=<year>", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I know the problem is in `res.data.i.title` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `res.data[i].Title`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: res.data[0] is undefined

Comment: That might be because of `?Year=<year>`  not retrieving the data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the element at the index `i` in your loop, like you would access a property of an object. To get the element at position `i` in your `res.data` array, you need the square bracket access `[ ]`

Also, you are not replacing the `year` parameters in your request for the `year` parameters passed to your function. You might want to check that out.

Here I have use the year `2018` as an example.

```js
function printTItles(year) {
  var res;
  
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      
      for(var i=0;i<res.per_page;i++){
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.data[i].Title;
      }
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies?Year=2018", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

printTItles();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

You could add some more improvement. For example, at each iteration, you are replacing the content of your `#demo` element. This cause only the last title to be shown. You could, instead, append the data to the already existing html of the div. Or, like I did in this case, build your string before setting it as the new `innerHTML` value.

```js
function printTItles(year) {
  var res;
  
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      
      var output = "";
      for(var i=0;i<res.per_page;i++){
        if(res.data[i]) {
          output += res.data[i].Title + '<br />';
        }
      }
      
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies?Year=2018", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

printTItles();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I've also added a condition to check if there is an element at `res.data[i]`.